# When processing string with Bash, how to treat comma differently depending on whether it's surrounded by some specific characters?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to transform a MySQL script into a JSON file and was asked to use Bash for it.
By writing a simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# I know this script just output each entry with its value, because I haven' t gone any further
for filename in $dir/home/*.sql
do
    cat $filename | while read line
    do
        names=${line%values*}
        names=${names#*(}
        names=${names%)*}
        values=${line#*values(}
        values=${values%)*}
        while [[ $names != $currentname ]]
        do
            currentname=${names%%,*}
            currentvalue=${values%%,*}
            echo $currentname
            echo $currentvalue
            names=${names#*,}
            values=${values#*,}
        done
    done
done
```

I have been basically able to fulfill the requirement. However, there is one more problem.
Some of the string entries has comma among its characters.

This causes a mistake that my script thinks these commas as the ones that separates values and thus a string bearing comma will be treated as two different strings.

It would be an easy task to solve this with programming languages like C++, but I have been asked to do this only with bash shell script although I am not familiar with it. So now I have been stuck with no clue. Maybe regular expression would be the cure? Or if there are other approaches please also help.

FYI, here is an example of the problem:

Input:

```
values(100, 'A100', 'A,100');
```

Expected output:

```
100
'A100'
'A,100'
```

Actual current output:

```
100
'A100'
'A
100'
```

Comment: `It would be an easy task to solve this with programming languages like C++` Writing a parser is easy?

Comment: As you said correctly, `bash` is not the first choice to write  a parser in. Looking at your input, it is syntactically like a [M4 macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4-1.4.15/html_node/Input-processing.html#Input-processing). You could based on the first word of the input, create a M4 macro definition which just outputs all its arguments, and, combined with the original input, creates the result you see. It's not the most elegant solution, but easier than writing a parser.

Comment: @ogmskdlksdrq : Your example makes me wonder: What is the expected output of `values("a,b", 'c,\' d')`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may help:

```
data="values(100, 'A100', 'A,100');"
json=${data//values(}
json=${json//);}
json=${json//, /$'\n'}
echo "$json"
```

Comment: This doesn't attempt to parse out the quoting at all, it just assumes that comma followed by space is a delimiter and other commas are not.

Comment: Yes, just like KISS

Answer (score 0):

> Expected output:

Typically in shell you would match it with a regex:

```
echo "values(100, 'A100', 'A,100');" | sed 's/values(//; s/\(, \|);\)/\n/g'
```

but this does not solve the problem at all.

The best and only solution is to write a real parser for real [mysql langauge](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html) to `'handle' '' ' ' 'all\tcorner\'cases'` properly. Read the input char by char, store state (ex. if you are inside quotation or not), handle `'\''` and other `\n` etc. sequences for the need of extracting the field. You might interest yourself in [mysql internal lexer (it's big!)](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/sql_lex.h) and lex and yacc programs.

Check  your scripts with http://shellcheck.net . Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 . Quote variable expansions. Don't be nominated for [useless cat award](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html).

> and was asked to use Bash for it.

Bash is a shell - it's primary role is to run and connect other programs with each other. Bash is a shell, not a full blown programming language, and writing programming stuff in it is going to be *very hard* or it just ends up using external programs, as that's what it's for. Write the parser in other language - use bash to run it. If you're comfortable in C++, write it in C++ inside a bash script, then compile and execute it inside a bash script.

Answer (score 0):

A common arrangement is to use regex for this, yes; for example, this is a requirement for parsing CSV files.  But you *can* parse the line piece by piece like in your attempt.

However, you have a number of [quoting errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) which would prevent your code from working even if you figured out a way to parse the input the way you want to. (And of course, get rid of the [Useless use of cat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat))

```sh
while read -r line; do
    case $line in
     *values\(*\)\; );;
     *) continue;;
    esac
    line=${line#values\(}
    line=${line%\)\;}
    while [ "$line" ]; do
        case $line in
         \'*)
            line=${line#\'}
            tail=${line#*\'}
            value=\'${line%"$tail"}
            line=${tail#,}
            line=${line# };;
         *) value=${line%%,*}
            line=${line#*,}
            line=${line# };;
       esac
       echo "$value"
    done
done <"$filename"
```

This is probably not really the way to go, just a hint if you really want to try to tackle this in Bash. I would write a simple parser in Python if I wanted to cover all bases.